# Have Directory Redirect to File in Directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, file, url, redirect

I was wondering if it is possible to have a domain like `www.example.com` and the have a directory like `www.example.com/test_dir` and in `test_dir` there is a file called `test.html` and another file called `test2.html` and with `.htaccess` or some other way have `www.example.com/test_dir` redirect to `www.example.com/test_dir/test.html`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test_dir/?$ test_dir/test.html [NC,L]
```

If you want the URL change. Use: `[NC,R=301,L]`